# Availability Groups - TL back up

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I have some questions on Availability Group

1. During server maintenance, if I fail over to Node2 and rebooted Node1. When Node1 comes back will the database sync automatically ?
2. Do i need to take backup of logs on both nodes to manage the space. If i run backup on node2, will i see the logfile freespace on node1

Answer (score 3):

> During server maintenance, if I fail over to Node2 and rebooted Node1. When Node1 comes back will the database sync automatically ?

By default, yes, unless some other issue has occurred which prevents this from happening.

> Do i need to take backup of logs on both nodes to manage the space. If i run backup on node2, will i see the logfile freespace on node1

It doesn't matter which node takes log backups, the log truncation lsn (at least for backups) will move forward on all replicas, thus you do not need to take log backups on all replicas.

Comment: Our issue is mainly with log truncation on the primary server. I am running the TL backups on the secondary; On the primary the TL size is growing.  Only workaround i see in here is to setup tl backup jobs on both servers and run it only on the current primary node

Comment: @user245321 The first problem is you didn't put that in the question. The second is what is the holdup reason? Look at sys.databases under log_reuse_wait_desc.